# JDBC Batch Updates and handling exceptions?

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-file, updates

In my process working with more than 40,000 records of data using JDBC. To improve the performance, i am using the PreparedStatement and batch updates.

Kindly required suggestions to handle the exception in batch updates? How to handle the exception , how to know the exception happened while processing 5001 record out of 40,000 record ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to write code which works out which one causes the error. I suggest using smaller batches of 10 to 100 depending on which gives you the best performance.

Comment: What kind of exception do you mean (any code examples)? I guess it's about transaction handling... it may make sense to 'chunk' a batch, e.g. commit your transaction after a certain number of updates (although this might lead to inconsistent data - at least logically).

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of BatchUpdateException. See the following code. You can figure out the error here.

```
try {
  // statements related to batch updates....
} catch (BatchUpdateException be) {
   //handle batch update exception
   be.printStackTrace();
   int[] counts = be.getUpdateCounts();
   for (int i=0; i<counts.length; i++) {
       System.out.println("Statement["+i+"] :"+counts[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing the Exception using getCause() and getNextException() you will finally find an JDBCException/SQLException.

Now, upcast to the congrete database-depend-exception and, for sure, you will find an identificator for the congrete problem/the congrete index (i.e. nr 5001).

Also try different JDBC-Drivers that has higher jdbc-versions (i.e. jdbc4).

Answer (score 0):

Use BatchUpdateException to handle exceptions for the batch updates